# Ошибка в typescript тип "true" не может быть назначен для типа ButtonHTMLAttributes<Boolean>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Пытаюсь в своем React приложении передать в пропс компонента Button свойство **disabled**.

Устанавливаю в interface тип **ButtonHTMLAttributes Boolean** и получаю ошибку: Тип "true" не может быть назначен для типа "ButtonHTMLAttributes Boolean | undefined"

**Как исправить?**

[image: Фото с ошибкой]

Comment: Вставляя код скриншотом Вы уменьшаете себе шанс получить ответ на Ваш вопрос - мало кто захочет перенабирать текст Вашего кода для проеврки его на своём компьютере. Чтобы вставить код, оберните его тремя апострофами (слева от клавиши 1 на клавиатуре) с каждой стороны

Answer (score 1):

Наверное надо писать

```
<button disabled={disabled}>
```

Comment: Это не исправляет мою ошибку, все так же выдается ошибка - "Тип "true" не может быть назначен для типа "ButtonHTMLAttributes Boolean | undefined""

Comment: может не стоит одинаково называть? Сделать isDisable, например `disabled={isDisabled}`